# Syntax error whatever I write under an if statement

Tags: python, arrays, list, syntax, split

I'm struggling over this, and maybe is something that I can't see but is simple...

```
import subprocess, pprint
cmd = subprocess.Popen('bhosts', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
errorCode = 0
description =""
arrayprova=[]
for linea in cmd.stdout:
    if "ok" not in linea and "closed" not in linea and "HOST_NAME" not in linea:
        arrayprova = linea.split()
        description = description + "host " + arrayprova[0] + "is " + arrayprova[1] 
        errorCode = 1
print arrayprova[1]
if errorCode == 0:
    description ="Everything is just fine."
print description
```

I get this error:

```
  File "bhosts_nodes_check.py", line 9
    description = description + "host " + arrayprova[0] + "is " + arrayprova[1]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces in your editor:

```
>>> '''\
...         arrayprova = linea.split()
...                 description = description + "host " + arrayprova[0] + "is " + arrayprova[1] 
... '''
'        arrayprova = linea.split()\n\t\tdescription = description + "host " + arrayprova[0] + "is " + arrayprova[1] \n'
>>> # ^^^ spaces here - but tabs here ^^^^
...
```

Python expands tabs to every 8th column, but you probably have your editor set to using only 4 spaces for a tab, further increasing the confusion. Your `arrayprova` line is indented to 8 spaces, while the two tabs on the next line are expanded to *16* spaces.

Don't ever use a mix indentation styles; stick to either only tabs or only spaces.

You can configure most editors to use spaces *only* for indentation, where pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key results in spaces being written. This is what the [Python styleguide (PEP 8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends:

> ### Tabs or Spaces?
>
> Never mix tabs and spaces.
>
> The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only. The second-most popular way is with tabs only. Code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively. When invoking the Python command line interpreter with the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are highly recommended!
>
> For new projects, spaces-only are strongly recommended over tabs. Most editors have features that make this easy to do.

Comment: Wish a stroke of a tab button would just generate four spaces in all editors.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: that's easily configured.